# What do low_memory and memory_map flags do in pd.read_csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

the function signature for `pandas.read_csv` gives, among others, the following options:

```
read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, low_memory=True, memory_map=False, iterator=False, chunksize=None, ...)
```

I couldn't find any documentation for either `low_memory`or `memory_map` flags. I am confused about whether these features are implemented yet and if so how do they work.

Specifically,

1. `memory_map`: If implemented does it use `np.memmap` and if so does it store the individual columns as memmap or the rows.
2. `low_memory`: Does it specify something like `cache` to store in memory?
3. can we convert an existing `DataFrame` to a *memmapped* `DataFrame`

**P.S.** : versions of relevant modules

```
pandas==0.14.0
scipy==0.14.0
numpy==1.8.1
```

Comment: ``low_memory`` should prob be documented (though it is an older option that doesn't really do much). ``memory_map`` is not documented because its not implemented (nor does it do anything). So the answer to your questions are all no.

Comment: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5888

Comment: FYI, these are not in the public doc-strings either, so not sure where you are looking.

Comment: I will revise slightly, ``memory_map`` is technically defined and tested. Never seen it used. Give it a try and report back. (it doesn't use ``np.memmap``, but just holds a limited amount of data in-memory). But I think this is an older / deprecated option anyhow.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff! I did a ``help(pd.read_csv)`` to get the docstrings. Thanks for the github reference.

Comment: Btw, I passed True to the two flags separately and the df loaded correctly - not sure whether it did a ``memmap`` tho'

Comment: yeh, never saw that option before! (its default False). as I said, might be old as ``read_csv`` is quite efficient in memory space so prob not necessary.

Comment: Maybe relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251219/low-memory-option-in-read-csv

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas read\_csv low\_memory and dtype options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251219/pandas-read-csv-low-memory-and-dtype-options)

Comment: thanks for the comment @AMC. The accepted answer from was very helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will attempt to sum up the comments to this question and also add my own research into one comprehensive answer.

1. `low_memory` option is **kind of** depricated, as in that it does not actually do anything anymore ([source](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5888)).
2. `memory_map` does not seem to use the numpy memory map as far as I can tell from the [source code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/1d8717446d8666207b63ae324e56be60a0b01b07/pandas/src/parser/io.c) It seems to be an option for how to parse the incoming stream of data, not something that matters for how the dataframe you receive works.
3. Since my assumption in point 2 is that this is only for parsing, this question is kind of irrelevant.