# Pandas read_csv: low_memory and dtype options

Tags: python, parsing, numpy, pandas, dataframe

```
df = pd.read_csv('somefile.csv')
```

...gives an error:

> .../site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py:1130:
> DtypeWarning: Columns (4,5,7,16) have mixed types.  Specify dtype
> option on import or set low_memory=False.

Why is the `dtype` option related to `low_memory`, and why might `low_memory=False` help?

Comment: I have a question about this warning. Is the index of the columns mentioned 0-based? For example column 4 which has a mixed type, is that df[:,4] or df[:,3]

Comment: @maziar when reading a csv, by default a new 0-based index is created and used.

Answer (score 718, accepted):

## The deprecated low_memory option

The `low_memory` option is not properly deprecated, but it should be, since it does not actually do anything differently[[source](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5888)]

The reason you get this `low_memory` warning is because guessing dtypes for each column is very memory demanding. Pandas tries to determine what dtype to set by analyzing the data in each column.

## Dtype Guessing (very bad)

Pandas can only determine what dtype a column should have once the whole file is read. This means nothing can really be parsed before the whole file is read unless you risk having to change the dtype of that column when you read the last value.

Consider the example of one file which has a column called user_id.
It contains 10 million rows where the user_id is always numbers.
Since pandas cannot know it is only numbers, it will probably keep it as the original strings until it has read the whole file.

## Specifying dtypes (should always be done)

adding

```
dtype={'user_id': int}
```

to the [`pd.read_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) call will make pandas know when it starts reading the file, that this is only integers.

Also worth noting is that if the last line in the file would have `"foobar"` written in the `user_id` column, the loading would crash if the above dtype was specified.

#### Example of broken data that breaks when dtypes are defined

```
import pandas as pd
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO


csvdata = """user_id,username
1,Alice
3,Bob
foobar,Caesar"""
sio = StringIO(csvdata)
pd.read_csv(sio, dtype={"user_id": int, "username": "string"})

ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: 'foobar'
```

dtypes are typically a numpy thing, read more about them here:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html

## What dtypes exists?

We have access to numpy dtypes: float, int, bool, timedelta64[ns] and datetime64[ns]. Note that the numpy date/time dtypes are *not* time zone aware.

Pandas extends this set of dtypes with its own:

`'datetime64[ns, <tz>]'` Which is a time zone aware timestamp.

'category' which is essentially an enum (strings represented by integer keys to save

'period[]' Not to be confused with a timedelta, these objects are actually anchored to specific time periods

'Sparse', 'Sparse[int]', 'Sparse[float]' is for sparse data or 'Data that has a lot of holes in it' Instead of saving the NaN or None in the dataframe it omits the objects, saving space.

'Interval' is a topic of its own but its main use is for indexing. [See more here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-intervalindex)

'Int8', 'Int16', 'Int32', 'Int64', 'UInt8', 'UInt16', 'UInt32', 'UInt64' are all pandas specific integers that are nullable, unlike the numpy variant.

'string' is a specific dtype for working with string data and gives access to the `.str` attribute on the series.

'boolean' is like the numpy 'bool' but it also supports missing data.

Read the complete reference here:

[Pandas dtype reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html)

## Gotchas, caveats, notes

Setting `dtype=object` will silence the above warning, but will not make it more memory efficient, only process efficient if anything.

Setting `dtype=unicode` will not do anything, since to numpy, a `unicode` is represented as `object`.

#### Usage of converters

@sparrow correctly points out the usage of converters to avoid pandas blowing up when encountering `'foobar'` in a column specified as `int`. I would like to add that converters are really heavy and inefficient to use in pandas and should be used as a last resort. This is because the read_csv process is a single process.

CSV files can be processed line by line and thus can be processed by multiple converters in parallel more efficiently by simply cutting the file into segments and running multiple processes, something that pandas does not support. But this is a different story.

Comment: So, given that setting a `dtype=object` is not more memory efficient, is there any reason to mess with it besides getting rid of the error?

Comment: @zthomas.nc yes, Pandas does not need to bother testing what is in the column. Theoretically saving some memory while loading (but none after loading is complete) and theoretically saving some cpu cycles (which you won't notice since disk I/O will be the bottleneck.

Comment: "Also worth noting is that if the last line in the file would have "foobar" written in the user_id column, the loading would crash if the above dtype was specified." is there some "coerce" option that could be used to throw away this row instead of crashing?

Comment: @sparrow there may be, but last time I used it it had bugs. It may be fixed in the latest version of pandas. `error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=True` should do the trick. The documentation says it's only valid with the C parser. It also says the default parser is None which makes it hard to know which one is the default.

Comment: "cutting the file into segments and running multiple processes, something that python does not support."   The preceding statement is categorically false.

Comment: @GeoffreyAnderson s/python/pandas/, or do you care to elaborate on some other falsehood?

Comment: Is there some convenient way to produce the right dtype setting based on a small sample? I'd be fine with just having to do it all carefully by hand if the initial say 100 or 1000 rows weren't consistent with the rest of the file. But manually typing in dicts for knock-off analysis tasks is painful.

Comment: @nealmcb You can read the dataframe with `nrows=100` as an argument and then do `df.dtypes` to see the dtypes you get. However, when reading the whole dataframe with these dtypes, be sure to do a `try/except` so you catch faulty dtype guesses. Data is dirty you know.

Comment: Re @GeoffreyAnderson comment:  I guess he was objecting to the "python" typo instead of "pandas" (which has since been corrected), but even in pandas there is the `chunksize` iterator which let's you divide the read into sections (I'm not sure about any multiprocessing capability here, but in the interest of memory management `chunksize` can still be helpful.

Comment: Theoretically I understand it's definitely better to specify all col_types ahead of time, but is there some pragmatic solution for when you have thousands of columns? For instance I want to only specify the dtypes of the columns that throw mixed type warnings

Comment: I'd only change "always" to "almost always". I have 24k columns with mixed dtypes, which would be one messy looking ```dtype={}``` specification. It may be inefficient, but it still only takes 10 seconds to read in, which is totally acceptable to me.

Comment: @JamesPaulMason If you load it once, you can do `df.dtypes.to_csv('dtypes.csv')` and save the dtypes for future use, easy. But yeah, if it isn't broken, I'm not gonna bash you for not fixing it.

Comment: Nice! Didn't even think of doing that! Pretty clever. If things explode further and it starts taking > 20 seconds to load then I'll implement this

Comment: @firelynx **Specifying dtypes**: what dtypes are accepted by this argument to the call?

Comment: @CheTesta Added dtype rerefence in the answer

Comment: @firelynx Is there a better alternative for dtype=object in terms of memory usage?

Comment: @RuthgerRighart If your data consists of random strings, then no. Numbers should be int or float, dates should be parsed as dates. If you have strings that aren't random you can use categorical. Nothing is worse than object, but some data can't be anything else.

Comment: is there also a string datatype for pandas now?

Comment: @baxx yes, since pandas 1.0.0 https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.arrays.StringArray.html#pandas.arrays.StringArray

Comment: Just in case it helps someone... I went round and round and round with this tyring all sorts of things with nothing working. Then it dawned on me: the column names in my CVS were upper case, but I had them lower case in my python script. Might seem obvious, but SQL is my native language, and in most cases there, column name case does not matter. But bottom line, adding a dtype={} solved the problem for me.

Comment: I believe `low_memory=False` is different from `low_memory=True`.   `low_memory=True` may result in multiple types within the same column (called mixed types) and `low_memory=False` will read the data twice, inferring the types as discussed in this answer.  It would be good to accurately describe how the two options behave.

Comment: For large datasets, setting `dtype='str'` and then manually parsing any columns that require it to numeric types after the fact often works reasonably well.  Of course, explicitly naming the columns and types expected in the file can help future maintainers.

Comment: imagine your df has 100s of columns, you wouldn't want to individually set the data type for each, therefore you need pandas to guess. Is there a way of guessing the first n rows in a df? So could set this number quite high.

Comment: @TheoF I imagine that if you have a large number of columns you have a large surface area for things to go wrong and you are doing yourself a favour by going through the dtypes. Maybe all your dtypes are the same and you know it, in that case you should be able to optimise your work a bit. But generally, I think it's time well invested.

Comment: @firelynx ok let me re-phrase, imagine a scenario where you have a csv file come in weekly which has 100s of columns, but each week there may be changes in either a) the number of columns, or b) the data types within these columns. I agree it's robust to go through and set dtypes, but for a scenario I describe, you'd need pandas to infer/guess each week.

Comment: @TheoF If the column names gives you a hint, you can read them, make some assumptions on certain columns and include them in the dtype specification when you read the dataset. Apart from that, I would let pandas guess, but then set up some hard validation rules on the dataset just to make sure the dataframe looks ok. There should be some rules to your data that you can check.
Also, test your code with weird datasets. Generate some ghastly datasets to make sure your code is robust. Pandas has the ability to go completely haywire without giving actual errors if fed data of the wrong type/format

Answer (score 79):

Try:

```
dashboard_df = pd.read_csv(p_file, sep=',', error_bad_lines=False, index_col=False, dtype='unicode')
```

According to the pandas documentation:

> dtype : Type name or dict of column -> type

As for low_memory, it's True [by default](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) and isn't yet documented. I don't think its relevant though. The error message is generic, so you shouldn't need to mess with low_memory anyway. Hope this helps and let me know if you have further problems

Comment: Adding `dtype=unicode` produced: `NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined`. But putting `unicode` in quotes (as in 'unicode') appears to work!

Comment: @sedeh You can specify dtypes either as python types or as `numpy.dtype('unicode')`. When you give the dtype option a string, it will try to cast it via the `numpy.dtype()` factory by default. Specifying `'unicode'` will actually not do anything, unicodes are just upcasted to `objects`. You will get `dtype='object'`

Answer (score 67):

```
df = pd.read_csv('somefile.csv', low_memory=False)
```

This should solve the issue. I got exactly the same error, when reading 1.8M rows from a CSV.

Comment: This silences the error, but does not actually change anything else.

Comment: I have same problem while running 1.5gb datafile

Comment: show this error when i tried ,
C error: out of memory

Comment: what is low_memory = False doing exactly ? Is it solving the issue or just not showing the error message?

Comment: @JSVJ I think setting low_memory = False solves the problem now (see my answer). It seems there was a time when it was going to be deprecated, but that didn't happen.

Comment: Jut be careful, doing this may result in pandas guessing different dtypes than with low_memory=True. It may silence the error but double check for potential silent bugs.

Answer (score 32):

This worked for me!

```
file = pd.read_csv('example.csv', engine='python')
```

Comment: Also here, 1+ million rows, appreciated

Comment: Rather than add yet another answer, I also found `file = pd.read_csv('example.csv', encoding='utf-8', engine='python')` worked best with sql exports and anything mangled by Excel

Comment: Oh, you might also add `, on_bad_lines='warn'`

Answer (score 23):

As mentioned earlier by firelynx if dtype is explicitly specified and there is mixed data that is not compatible with that dtype then loading will crash. I used a converter like this as a workaround to change the values with incompatible data type so that the data could still be loaded.

```
def conv(val):
    if not val:
        return 0    
    try:
        return np.float64(val)
    except:        
        return np.float64(0)

df = pd.read_csv(csv_file,converters={'COL_A':conv,'COL_B':conv})
```

Answer (score 7):

It worked for me with `low_memory = False` while importing a DataFrame. That is all the change that worked for me:

```
df = pd.read_csv('export4_16.csv',low_memory=False)
```

Comment: This answer is the same answer as [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33161955/1983957) and just silences the error but does not change anything else as pointed out by firelynx

Answer (score 7):

I was facing a similar issue when processing a huge csv file (6 million rows). I had three issues:

1. the file contained strange characters (fixed using encoding)
2. the datatype was not specified (fixed using dtype property)
3. Using the above I still faced an issue which was related with the file_format that could not be defined based on the filename (fixed using try .. except..)

```
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file,sep=';', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1',
                     names=['permission','owner_name','group_name','size','ctime','mtime','atime','filename','full_filename'],
                     dtype={'permission':str,'owner_name':str,'group_name':str,'size':str,'ctime':object,'mtime':object,'atime':object,'filename':str,'full_filename':str,'first_date':object,'last_date':object})
    
    try:
        df['file_format'] = [Path(f).suffix[1:] for f in df.filename.tolist()]
    except:
        df['file_format'] = ''
```

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes, when all else fails, you just want to tell pandas to shut up about it:

```
# Ignore DtypeWarnings from pandas' read_csv                                                                                                                                                                                            
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', message="^Columns.*")
```

Comment: This doesn’t solve the problem. It just hides it

Comment: Depends on whether the warning itself is the problem.

Answer (score 6):

As the error says, you should specify the datatypes when using the `read_csv()` method.
So, you should write

```
file = pd.read_csv('example.csv', dtype='unicode')
```

Answer (score 5):

According to the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), specifying `low_memory=False` as long as the `engine='c'` (which is the default) is a reasonable solution to this problem.

If `low_memory=False`, then whole columns will be read in first, and then the proper types determined. For example, the column will be kept as objects (strings) as needed to preserve information.

If `low_memory=True` (the default), then pandas reads in the data in chunks of rows, then appends them together. Then some of the columns might look like chunks of integers and strings mixed up, depending on whether during the chunk pandas encountered anything that couldn't be cast to integer (say). This could cause problems later. The warning is telling you that this happened at least once in the read in, so you should be careful. Setting `low_memory=False` will use more memory but will avoid the problem.

Personally, I think `low_memory=True` is a bad default, but I work in an area that uses many more small datasets than large ones and so convenience is more important than efficiency.

The following code illustrates an example where `low_memory=True` is set and a column comes in with mixed types. It builds off the answer by @firelynx

```
import pandas as pd
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO

# make a big csv data file, following earlier approach by @firelynx
csvdata = """1,Alice
2,Bob
3,Caesar
"""

# we have to replicate the "integer column" user_id many many times to get
# pd.read_csv to actually chunk read. otherwise it just reads 
# the whole thing in one chunk, because it's faster, and we don't get any 
# "mixed dtype" issue. the 100000 below was chosen by experimentation.
csvdatafull = ""
for i in range(100000):
    csvdatafull = csvdatafull + csvdata
csvdatafull =  csvdatafull + "foobar,Cthlulu\n"
csvdatafull = "user_id,username\n" + csvdatafull

sio = StringIO(csvdatafull)
# the following line gives me the warning:
    # C:\Users\rdisa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3072: DtypeWarning: Columns (0) have mixed types.Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
    # interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
# but it does not always give me the warning, so i guess the internal workings of read_csv depend on background factors
x = pd.read_csv(sio, low_memory=True) #, dtype={"user_id": int, "username": "string"})

x.dtypes
# this gives:
# Out[69]: 
# user_id     object
# username    object
# dtype: object

type(x['user_id'].iloc[0]) # int
type(x['user_id'].iloc[1]) # int
type(x['user_id'].iloc[2]) # int
type(x['user_id'].iloc[10000]) # int
type(x['user_id'].iloc[299999]) # str !!!! (even though it's a number! so this chunk must have been read in as strings)
type(x['user_id'].iloc[300000]) # str !!!!!
```

Aside: To give an example where this is a problem (and where I first encountered this as a serious issue), imagine you ran `pd.read_csv()` on a file then wanted to drop duplicates based on an identifier. Say the identifier is sometimes numeric, sometimes string. One row might be "81287", another might be "97324-32". Still, they are unique identifiers.

With `low_memory=True`, pandas might read in the identifier column like this:

```
81287
81287
81287
81287
81287
"81287"
"81287"
"81287"
"81287"
"97324-32"
"97324-32"
"97324-32"
"97324-32"
"97324-32"
```

Just because it chunks things and so, sometimes the identifier 81287 is a number, sometimes a string. When I try to drop duplicates based on this, well,

```
81287 == "81287"
Out[98]: False
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with a ~400MB file. Setting `low_memory=False` did the trick for me. Do the simple things first,I would check that your dataframe isn't bigger than your system memory, reboot, clear the RAM before proceeding. If you're still running into errors, its worth making sure your `.csv` file is ok, take a quick look in Excel and make sure there's no obvious corruption. Broken original data can wreak havoc...

Answer (score 2):

Building on the answer given by Jerald Achaibar we can detect the mixed Dytpes warning and only use the slower python engine when the warning occurs:

```
import warnings

# Force mixed datatype warning to be a python error so we can catch it and reattempt the 
# load using the slower python engine
warnings.simplefilter('error', pandas.errors.DtypeWarning)
try:
    df = pandas.read_csv(path, sep=sep, encoding=encoding)
except pandas.errors.DtypeWarning:
    df = pandas.read_csv(path, sep=sep, encoding=encoding, engine="python")
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me!

```
dashboard_df = pd.read_csv(p_file, sep=';', error_bad_lines=False, index_col=False, dtype='unicode')
```