# Pandas read_csv on 6.5 GB file consumes more than 170GB RAM

Tags: python, parsing, pandas, numpy, ipython

I wanted to bring this up, just because it's crazy weird.  Maybe Wes has some idea. The file is pretty regular: 1100 rows x ~3M columns, data are tab-separated, consisting solely of the integers 0, 1, and 2.  Clearly this is not expected.

If I prepopulate a dataframe as below, it consumes ~26GB of RAM.

```
h = open("ms.txt")
header = h.readline().split("\t")
h.close()
rows=1100
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=header, index=range(rows), dtype=int)
```

System info:

- python 2.7.9
- ipython 2.3.1
- numpy 1.9.1
- pandas 0.15.2.

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: What Python version is this?

Comment: does it act differently if you transpose the data? 10^3 rows and 10^6 seems...backwards.

Comment: what does this mean: "data is all 0/1/2"?

Comment: @PaulH: Probably means his data in the rows are all just 0s, 1s, and 2s.

Comment: @PaulH: sorry, exactly that.  it's genotype data, literally the characters 0, 1, and 2.

Comment: I'm curious about what the contents of `ms.txt` are. You call `readline()` on it, which means it's a multi-line text file, but then you `split` it. Can you post maybe the first 10 rows just to be sure?

Comment: @SimeonVisser: python 2.7.9, ipython 2.3.1, numpy 1.9.1, pandas 0.15.2.

Comment: @TheLaughingMan: that's just to get the header information to specify the number of columns in the data.  The first three data rows look like this (in numpy):

array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0., ...,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0., ...,  1.,  0.,  1.],

Comment: I see, so it's `readline` and not `readlines`. My bad. The first one of course only reads one line. By any chance, what's the file size of `ms.txt`?

Comment: Currently processing like this: we'll see what happens. https://gist.github.com/cfriedline/9b462b1f4696b2e6dcc3

Comment: @TheLaughingMan 6.5GB ish.

Comment: This may be super naive, but why isn't that the right memory? For example if I do `np.zeros((1100, 3000000)).nbytes / 1e9` I get `26.4`. The dtype is `float64`.

Comment: try telling `read_csv` that everything will be an integer.

Comment: @prpl.mnky.dshwshr: 26.4GB i can deal with, per the title of this post 170GB is crazy and weird.

Comment: I'm assuming you've tried doing it like this: `with open("ms.txt")  as f: header = [x.split("\t") for x in f.readline()]` ?

Comment: @TheLaughingMan: check out the gist link ;-)

Comment: This is insane. I've seen a `pandas` benchmark test before with 50GB of data used and I don't remember it using 170GB of RAM.

Comment: @TheLaughingMan Agreed.  I've got a box with huge ram that I can run this on, but it didn't seem to want to stop.  I killed it manually at 170GB.  Who knows how big it would have gotten?

Comment: Well if I try `np.zeros((1100, 3000000), dtype=object)` it just hangs, but I'm guessing I'm going to see memory consumption much much higher. Perhaps `read_csv` is doing this, and making some copies of a few things, as it attempts to discern data types while reading?

Comment: @prpl.mnky.dshwshr perhaps. once i get the work done I actually have to do, i'll experiment with the data type.

Comment: Digging through the stuff under `read_csv` it looks like in the generic case it bottoms out with `pandas.io.parsers.PythonParser.read` which does appear to make copies during date converstion and in `_convert_data` which calls to `_convert_to_ndarrays` which calls to `_convert_types` which then has further calls to some functions like `maybe_convert_numeric`, etc. Anywhere along this trail of code you could be getting blowup from `object` type and from inefficient copying.

Comment: To come at it from the other side: by manually creating a DataFrame 1100x3M of dtype int8, the total memory usage after construction should be about ~3.1G as expected.  In the past, there have been corners of pandas which don't handle the many-columns-few-rows limits very well, so that could also be playing a role.

Comment: Thanks everyone, adding a numpy int16 array is just under 7GB which works fine for my purposes.  Glad I'm not totally crazy.  Will def try out dtype in read_csv in a bit.

Answer (score 8):

## Problem of your example.

Trying your code on small scale, I notice even if you set `dtype=int`, you are actually ending up with `dtype=object` in your resulting dataframe.

```
header = ['a','b','c']
rows = 11
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=header, index=range(rows), dtype=int)

df.dtypes
a    object
b    object
c    object
dtype: object
```

This is because even though you give the `pd.read_csv` function the instruction that the columns are `dtype=int`, it cannot override the dtypes being ultimately determined by the data in the column.

This is because pandas is [*tightly coupled*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)#Types_of_coupling) to numpy and numpy dtypes.

The problem is, there is no data in your created dataframe, thus numpy defaults the data to be `np.NaN`, which does *not fit* in an integer.

This means numpy gets confused and defaults back to the dtype being `object`.

### Problem of the object dtype.

Having the dtype set to `object` means a big overhead in memory consumption and allocation time compared to if you would have the dtype set as integer or float.

### Workaround for your example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=header, index=range(rows), dtype=float)
```

This works just fine, since `np.NaN` can live in a float. This produces

```
a    float64
b    float64
c    float64
dtype: object
```

And should take less memory.

## More on how to relate to dtypes

See this related post for details on dtype:
[Pandas read_csv low_memory and dtype options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251219/low-memory-option-in-read-csv/27232309#27232309)

Answer (score 0):

The similar problem i had faced with 3 GB data today and i just did little change in my coding style like instead of file.read() and file.readline() method i used below code, that below code just load 1 line at a time in ram

```
import re

df_list = []

with open("ms.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        #process(line)
        line = line.strip()
        columns = re.split("\t", line, maxsplit=4) # you should modify these according to your split criteria
        df_list.append(columns)
```

Here is code to convert your data into pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(df_list)# here you will have to modify according to your data frame needs
```