# Why does reading a large csv in pandas without low_memory lead to an out of memory error despite having enough RAM?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, memory

I have a large csv file with 20.9 GB, it has 16 columns and over 170 million rows.

My computer has 128 GB RAM and Python can use all that is available.

When I try to read just two columns using `pandas.read_csv()` with `low_memory=False` I'm getting

> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory

I can read it fine with `low_memory=True`.

Can someone explain to me why this happens?

Comment: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219902/pandas-read-csv-on-6-5-gb-file-consumes-more-than-170gb-ram) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251219/pandas-read-csv-low-memory-and-dtype-options/27232309#27232309) can be of some help as well

Comment: Thanks for the links.