# Pandas/Python memory spike while reading 3.2 GB file

Tags: python, csv, pandas, memory

So I have been trying to read a 3.2GB file in memory using pandas `read_csv` function but I kept on running into some sort of memory leak, my memory usage would spike `90%+`.

So as alternatives

1. I tried defining `dtype` to avoid keeping the data in memory as strings, but saw similar behaviour.
2. Tried out numpy read csv, thinking I would get some different results but was definitely wrong about that.
3. Tried reading line by line ran into the same problem, but really slowly.
4. I recently moved to python 3, so thought there could be some bug there, but saw similar results on python2 + pandas.

The file in question is a train.csv file from a kaggle competition [grupo bimbo](https://www.kaggle.com/c/grupo-bimbo-inventory-demand/)

System info:

`RAM: 16GB, Processor: i7 8cores`

Let me know if you would like to know anything else.

Thanks :)

EDIT 1: its a memory spike! not a leak (sorry my bad.)

EDIT 2: Sample of the csv file

```
Semana,Agencia_ID,Canal_ID,Ruta_SAK,Cliente_ID,Producto_ID,Venta_uni_hoy,Venta_hoy,Dev_uni_proxima,Dev_proxima,Demanda_uni_equil
3,1110,7,3301,15766,1212,3,25.14,0,0.0,3
3,1110,7,3301,15766,1216,4,33.52,0,0.0,4
3,1110,7,3301,15766,1238,4,39.32,0,0.0,4
3,1110,7,3301,15766,1240,4,33.52,0,0.0,4
3,1110,7,3301,15766,1242,3,22.92,0,0.0,3
```

EDIT 3: number rows in the file **74180465**

Other then a simple `pd.read_csv('filename', low_memory=False)`

I have tried

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
my_data = genfromtxt('data/train.csv', delimiter=',')
```

**UPDATE**
The below code just worked, but I still want to get to the bottom of this problem, there must be something wrong.

```
import pandas as pd
import gc
data = pd.DataFrame()
data_iterator = pd.read_csv('data/train.csv', chunksize=100000)
for sub_data in data_iterator:
    data.append(sub_data)
    gc.collect()
```

[image]

[image]

EDIT: **Piece of Code that worked.**
Thanks for all the help guys, I had messed up my dtypes by adding python dtypes instead of numpy ones. Once I fixed that the below code worked like a charm.

```
dtypes = {'Semana': pd.np.int8,
          'Agencia_ID':pd.np.int8,
          'Canal_ID':pd.np.int8,
          'Ruta_SAK':pd.np.int8,
          'Cliente_ID':pd.np.int8,
          'Producto_ID':pd.np.int8,
          'Venta_uni_hoy':pd.np.int8,
          'Venta_hoy':pd.np.float16,
          'Dev_uni_proxima':pd.np.int8,
          'Dev_proxima':pd.np.float16,
          'Demanda_uni_equil':pd.np.int8}
data = pd.read_csv('data/train.csv', dtype=dtypes)
```

This brought down the memory consumption to just under 4Gb

Comment: That doesn't sound like a memory leak. That sounds like you're trying to read a huge file into memory all at once and incurring a huge amount of memory consumption to do so. (It's completely normal for the in-memory representation to be larger than the serialized form.)

Comment: memory leak = memory that is allocated but never freed. This is not the case here. A spike doesn't mean a memory leak at all.

Comment: @limbo thanks for the correction but 10Gb+ usage for a 3.2Gb file the numbers really feel wrong.

Comment: Can you write a sample line of the data?

Comment: @heaven00 no worries, we are all here to learn. I am a bit puzzled by that as well. Can you show us the code you use?

Comment: @chapelo added the sample of the csv file

Comment: When you said "spike", I was expecting an actual spike. This behavior (that's 1 min on the horizontal axis, I think) looks like your machine is just slowly running out of memory as you read in a large amount of data.

Comment: How many lines long is the file? Have you estimated how much memory you expect it to take?

Comment: @Richard I have other pictures, I just took the one where it was gradually increasing while I was reading line by line

Comment: @limbo udpated the question

Comment: @Richard added another picture with the spike

Comment: @heaven00, thanks. Could you post how many lines are in the file as well?

Comment: 3x size from serialized file to internal representation doesn't sound that unreasonable to me... The real issue is that you're holding the entire file in memory.. I would recommend using the csv library and writing your output to file as you go instead of saving the whole thing in memory

Comment: @heaven00: In the second picture, at what point do you begin reading the file? Is it a slow ramp followed by that spike, or just the spike?

Comment: @Aaron is 3x normal for pandas ? I want to load it in memory for data manipulations and analysis

Comment: @heaven00: Did you see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27232309/752843)?

Comment: @Richard the read function was running until the point of the fall

Comment: @Richard yes I tried with defining dtypes but still had the same issue

Comment: 3x feels right.. One for pd.DataFrame. one for read-csv another dataframe , one for append Dataframe which -- I think creates a copy. So, 3x feels right.

Comment: @Merlin i wasn't using append, which does create a copy initially

Comment: My gut feeling is that you are trying to analyze the data with the wrong tools. csv raw data isn't the best way to handle that amount of data, you should definitely put that in a database system and analyze or at least pre-filter there or you should read and analyze by smaller chunks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file stored in memory as text is not as compact as a compressed binary format, however it is relatively compact data-wise. If it's a simple ascii file, aside from any file header information, each character is only 1 byte. Python strings have a similar relation, where there's some overhead for internal python stuff, but each extra character adds only 1 byte (from testing with `__sizeof__`). Once you start converting to numeric types and collections (lists, arrays, data frames, etc.) the overhead will grow. A list for example must store a type and a value for each position, whereas a string only stores a value.

```
>>> s = '3,1110,7,3301,15766,1212,3,25.14,0,0.0,3\r\n'
>>> l = [3,1110,7,3301,15766,1212,3,25.14,0,0.0,3]
>>> s.__sizeof__()
75
>>> l.__sizeof__()
128
```

A little bit of testing (assuming `__sizeof__` is accurate):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10'
print ('string: '+str(s.__sizeof__())+'\n')
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
print ('list: '+str(l.__sizeof__())+'\n')
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
print ('array: '+str(a.__sizeof__())+'\n')
b = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], dtype=np.dtype('u1'))
print ('byte array: '+str(b.__sizeof__())+'\n')
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
print ('dataframe: '+str(df.__sizeof__())+'\n')
```

returns:

```
string: 53

list: 120

array: 136

byte array: 106

dataframe: 152
```

Comment: p = pd.DataFrame(l).__sizeof__() -- 160

Comment: wouldn't pandas `dtype` help in this matter ?
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: possibly... I'm not a big user of pandas, although I'm aware that it plays nice with numpy under the hood

Comment: @Aaron thanks you guys were spot on, I was adding the wrong dtypes. I used python dtypes which were causing issues. Changed them to numpy dtypes and worked like a charm, with total usage around 4Gb almost same as the filesize

Comment: @Richard thanks to you too, your link also had the similar answer I just messed up :)

Comment: I did a bit more testing, and `pd.DataFrame(b)` is the smalllest yet!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your second chart, it looks as though there's a brief period in time where your machine allocates an additional 4.368 GB of memory, which is approximately the size of your 3.2 GB dataset (assuming 1GB overhead, which might be a stretch).

I tried to track down a place where this could happen and haven't been super successful. Perhaps you can find it, though, if you're motivated. Here's the path I took:

[This line](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/parsers.py#L908) reads:

```
def read(self, nrows=None):
    if nrows is not None:
        if self.options.get('skip_footer'):
            raise ValueError('skip_footer not supported for iteration')

    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
```

Here, `_engine` references [`PythonParser`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/parsers.py#L1674).

That, in turn, calls [`_get_lines()`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/parsers.py#L2359).

That makes calls to a data [`source`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/parsers.py#L2379).

Which looks like it reads in in the form of strings from something relatively standard (see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/parsers.py#L1741)), like [TextIOWrapper](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper).

So things are getting read in as standard text and converted, this explains the slow ramp.

What about the spike? I think that's explained by [these lines](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/parsers.py#L908-L916):

```
ret = self._engine.read(nrows)

if self.options.get('as_recarray'):
    return ret

# May alter columns / col_dict
index, columns, col_dict = self._create_index(ret)

df = DataFrame(col_dict, columns=columns, index=index)
```

`ret` becomes all the components of a data frame`.

`self._create_index()` breaks `ret` apart into these components:

```
def _create_index(self, ret):
    index, columns, col_dict = ret
    return index, columns, col_dict
```

So far, everything can be done by reference, and the call to `DataFrame()` continues that trend (see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L251)).

So, if my theory is correct, `DataFrame()` is either copying the data somewhere, or `_engine.read()` is doing so somewhere along the path I've identified.

Comment: Wow thanks for the detailed answer, I think this was mostly happening because my dtypes were defined wrong and it was trying to find the exact dtypes for the data. but this is still an assumption so far.