# Pandas read_csv function possible to auto detect dtype?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large CSV file with over 200+ columns. Some of the columns are string, some varchar, some integers and some floats.

When i just read my csv file into a pandas dataframe, it is able to detect which are the numerical columns. However, it will give me the `specify dtype or low memory error` warning.

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
df_not_num = df_raw.select_dtypes(exclude =[np.number,np.int16,np.bool,np.float32])
print len(df)
>>>200
print len(list(df_not_num))
>>> 10
```

Then i try to specify a dtype: `dtype='unicode'`
But this causes all my columns to be objects. 
It is too much manual work to speicfy each dtype per column name when reading the CSV into a dataframe.

```
pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', dtype = 'unicode')
df_not_num = df_raw.select_dtypes(exclude =[np.number,np.int16,np.bool,np.float32])
print len(df)
>>>>200
print len(list(df_not_num))
>>> 200
```

So the only way to avoid the low memory warning is to specify a `dtype`. But how do i specify that i have mixed dtypes for different columns without having to manually specify the dtype of each of the 200 columns?

Comment: Just specifying "mixed types" won't help `read_csv`. You either have to specify particular types for some columns by passing a dict, e.g.: `{‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32}` or specify one dtype, which will try to be applied to all columns, or none. Also, there is no "varchar" type in Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas read\_csv low\_memory and dtype options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251219/pandas-read-csv-low-memory-and-dtype-options)

Answer (score 1):

You can read just the first row from the csv to have the list of column names:

```
col_names = pd.read_csv('file.csv', nrows=0).columns.tolist()
```

Then transform it into a dictionary `dtypes_dict={col_name: dtype}` based on the conditions you need.

Then use the dictionary of `dtypes` during reading:

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv', dtype=dtypes_dict)
```