# Proper way of writing and reading Dataframe to file in Python

Tags: python, file, pandas, dataframe

I would like to write and later read a dataframe in Python.

```
df_final.to_csv(self.get_local_file_path(hash,dataset_name), sep='\t', encoding='utf8')
...
df_final = pd.read_table(self.get_local_file_path(hash,dataset_name), encoding='utf8',index_col=[0,1])
```

But then I get:

> sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (7,17,28) have mixed types. Specify dtype
>   option on import or set low_memory=False.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251219/pandas-read-csv-low-memory-and-dtype-options). Which in the bottom line says I should specify the field types when I read the file because "low_memory" is deprecated... I find it very inefficient.

Isn't there a simple way to write & later read a Dataframe? I don't care about the human-readability of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pickle your dataframe:

```
df_final.to_pickle(self.get_local_file_path(hash,dataset_name))
```

Read it back later:

```
df_final = pd.read_pickle(self.get_local_file_path(hash,dataset_name))
```

If your dataframe ist big and this gets to slow, you might have more luck using the HDF5 format:

```
df_final.to_hdf(self.get_local_file_path(hash,dataset_name))
```

Read it back later:

```
df_final = pd.read_hdf(self.get_local_file_path(hash,dataset_name))
```

You might need to install PyTables first.

Both ways store the data along with their types. Therefore, this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is because Pandas has detected conflicting Data values in your Column. You can specify the datatypes in the DataFrame Constructor if you wish.

```
,dtype={'FIELD':int,'FIELD2':str}
```

Etc.