# pandas to_csv read_csv encoding error

Tags: python, pandas, csv, utf-8, python-unicode

I build a dataframe  in pandas (v21.1) (Python 3, Windows (220k rows) and write out to csv.
Open in Excel and file looks fine (220k rows).
Read in using pandas and now the file has an additional 40k rows and often has various encoding errors.

Have tried multiple `to_csv`/ `read_csv` `encoding=` combinations, including:
`utf-8`, `utf-8-sig`, `cp1252`, `ascii` and  `utf-16`
Write out:

```
encoding='cp1252' or 'ascii' - UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u1e28' in position 261: character maps to <undefined>
encoding='utf-8',`utf-8-sig`,`utf-16`,`cp1252`,  - no Python error in the console, but still doesn't render correctly when I import it again.
```

When reading in I often get the warning:
`DtypeWarning: Columns (0,1,3,4,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,46,47,48,49,50,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)`

I have tried specifying the `dtypes` for the columns, by saving the `dtypes`dict when `to_csv` and using the same dict as input for `read_csv` - but it also gave an error because unexpected datatypes found, e.g. `ValueError: Integer column has NA values in column 33`

When I do it out/in as Excel file, it seems to work fine.
When I try with Python 2.7 installation, same issue occurs.

I suspect the issue is possibly with a 3rd-party csv file that I import, which only seems to import when I use 'cp1252'. I tried resaved this input file in Excel using utf-8 - but this hasn't worked either.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Which seperator are you using?   This may cause additional rows in csv if it is not properly addressed.

Comment: @Ryu I have only tried with ','

Comment: Does the csv file contains any commas other than the seperator? If yes I will suggest you to use another seperator  when reading the csv..

Answer (score 0):

`DtypeWarning` which you are getting is because pandas could not deduce the data type of all those columns. Setting them `str` in the `dtype` param will silence the warning.

Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27232309/5182482

> Read in using pandas and now the file has an additional 40k rows and often has various encoding errors.

I can not exactly tell you about this issue.