# Pandas read_csv low_memory and dtype options. TypeError: Cannot cast array from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am trying to read a csv file

```
df = pd.read_csv('Salaries.csv')
```

I have this:

> sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (3,4,5,6,12) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.

So, I tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Salaries.csv', sep=',', dtype={
'Id': int, 
'EmployeeName': str, 
'JobTitle': str, 
'BasePay': float,
'OvertimePay': float, 
'OtherPay': float, 
'Benefits': float, 
'TotalPay': np.float64,
'TotalPayBenefits': np.float64,
'Year': np.int64,
'Notes': np.float64,
'Agency': str,
'Status': float})
```

And now I have this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1156, in
> pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens TypeError: Cannot cast
> array from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'

Also I have read previously asked questions and official docs but don't understand where the problem is.

Here is example of data from Salaries.csv

> Id,EmployeeName,JobTitle,BasePay,OvertimePay,OtherPay,Benefits,TotalPay,TotalPayBenefits,Year,Notes,Agency,Status
>
> 1,NATHANIEL FORD,GENERAL MANAGER-METROPOLITAN TRANSIT AUTHORITY,167411.18,0.0,400184.25,,567595.43,567595.43,2011,,San Francisco,

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251219/pandas-read-csv-low-memory-and-dtype-options)

Comment: Have you tried speficying a dtype of `O` for those columns with mixed types? Right now you are forcing a dtype of `float64`on columns that have mixed types, which of course raises and error.

Comment: The type for the last column Status should be object

Comment: @AlexandreNixon Thanks, it has helped. But columns 7 and 8 are casted to 567595 instead of 567595.43. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: run the first line of code again: `df = pd.read_csv('Salaries.csv')` and do `print(df.dtypes)` to compare the infered dtypes from the ones you're writing explicitly. May give you some insight, at least see which are the offending columns

Comment: @Robert have tried and after that used all above data types, but helped to use object in mixed columns.

Comment: maybe there are characters in the file that can't be converted to floats? Read everything in as `np.object`. then do `msk = df[obj_col].str.isnumeric()` then `print(df[msk])` to see if there's any surprises in there. If there is you can always do: `df.loc[~msk, obj_col] = np.nan` and then `df[obj_col] = df[obj_col].astype(float)`

Comment: @Robert in csv file were a lot of str in position "BasicPay", so I've deleted them and now it works. But Thanks a lot!