# Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using the following code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/Python Test/AcquirerRussell3000.csv')
```

I have the following type of data:

```
18.07.2000  27.1875         0 08.08.2000  25.3125       0.1 05.09.2000  \
0   19.07.00  26.6250 -0.020690   09.08.00  25.2344 -0.003085   06.09.00   
1   20.07.00  26.6250  0.000000   10.08.00  25.1406 -0.003717   07.09.00   
2   21.07.00  25.6875 -0.035211   11.08.00  25.5781  0.017402   08.09.00   
3   24.07.00  26.2500  0.021898   14.08.00  25.4375 -0.005497   11.09.00   
4   25.07.00  26.6875  0.016667   15.08.00  25.5625  0.004914   12.09.00
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Pythone Test/untitled0.py:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (long list of numbers) have mixed types. 
Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
```

So every 3rd column is a date the rest are numbers. I guess there is no single dtype since dates are strings and the rest is a float or int? I have about 5000 columns or more and around 400 rows.

I have seen similar questions to this but dont quite know how to apply this to my data. Furthermore I want to run the following code after to stack the data frame.

```
a = np.arange(len(df.columns))
df.columns = [a % 3, a // 3]
df = df.stack().reset_index(drop=True)

df.to_csv('AcquirerRussell3000stacked.csv', sep=',')
```

What dtype should I use? Or should I just set low_memory to false?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This solved my problem from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251219/pandas-read-csv-low-memory-and-dtype-options)

```
dashboard_df = pd.read_csv(p_file, sep=',', error_bad_lines=False, index_col=False, dtype='unicode')
```

Could anyone explain this answer to me tough?

Comment: it looks like "dtype='unicode'" does the thing

Comment: dtype="unicode"

Comment: this solved another of my problems. For some reason some of my columns were missing but the columns that were present had all it's data intact (rather than being shifted across to the wrong column). When I tried to list the columns and their dtypes separately I got the same error as the OP which led me here. For some reason including this dtype='unicode' option made it read in all the correct cols... I have no idea why or how but I'm very please nevertheless!

Answer (score 1):

`df = pd.read_csv('/Python Test/AcquirerRussell3000.csv', engine='python')`

or

`df = pd.read_csv('/Python Test/AcquirerRussell3000.csv', low_memory=False)`

does the trick for me.