# MemoryError during reading csv

Tags: mysql, pandas, csv, sqlalchemy

I am trying to read some information into Pandas DataFrame and facing the problem due to the value of the data.

**Specs of PC:**

RAM 32 GB

IntelCore i7 4GHz

**Setup:**

Data is in MySQL DB, 9 columns (7 int, 1 date, 1 DateTime). DB is on the local machine, so no internet bandwidth issues.
22 mil. rows of data.

Tried to read directly from MySQL server - it never ends.

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:@localhost:3306/database')

search_df = pd.read_sql_table('search', engine)
```

I checked with SO and got the impression that instead of using the connector, better to parse CSV. I exported table to CSV.

CSV file size - 1.5GB

**My code**

```
dtype = {
    'search_id' : int,
    'job_count_total' : int,
    'job_count_done' : int,
    'city_id_start' : int,
    'city_id_end' : int,
    'date_start' : str,
    'datetime_create' : str,
    'agent_id' : int,
    'ride_segment_found_cnt' : int
}

search_df = pd.read_csv('search.csv', sep=',', dtype=dtype)
```

I tried both engines, `c` and `python`, different chunk sizes, `low_memory` as `True` and `False`, specified dtypes and not, but still getting `MemoryError`.

I tried everything, mentioned in the question above (which was marked as of origin, mine as duplicate), but nothing changes.

I spotted only two difference:

If I parsing without chunks that I get Memory Error on parsing.

When I am parsing in chunks - on concatenation into one DF.

Also, chunking by 5_000_000 rows gives an error on parsing, less - on concatenation.

Here is an error message on concatenation:

```
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory
```

Comment: @Vaishali, I would like to disagree with you on the closure of the question. I tried everything that is mentioned in the post you added (different engines, dtypes, low memory and chunks, and nothing helped me). Could you reopen the question? Thank you in advance

Comment: I have reopened the question, this is the [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251219/pandas-read-csv-low-memory-and-dtype-options) link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the problem was with memory.
I played a bit with chunk-size + added some filtrations, that I had later in code on the chunk.
That allowed me to fit dataframe into memory.