# How to read file from Kaggle in Jupyter Notebook in Microsoft Azure?

Tags: python, jupyter, kaggle

I am using **Jupyter Notebook in Microsoft Azure**. Since I cannot upload big files in Azure, I need to read it from a link. The csv file I want to read is in Kaggle.

I did this:

```
!pip install kaggle

import os

os.environ['KAGGLE_USERNAME'] = "*********"

os.environ['KAGGLE_KEY'] = "*********"

import kaggle
```

But I don't know how to read the file now.
In other cases I use pandas to read files: 
`file = pd.read_csv("file/link")`
and then I am able to clean and organize my data.
But it is not working in this situation.
Could you please help me?

I want to be able to read and manipulate the data as with the pd.read_csv because I need it for my project in Data Science.
This is the dataset I want to be able to work with: https://www.kaggle.com/START-UMD/gtd#globalterrorismdb_0718dist.csv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Kaggle* has already provided extensive documentation for their command line API [here](https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api#api-credentials), which has been built using *Python* and the source can be found [here](https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api/tree/master/kaggle/api) so reverse engineering it is very straight forward in order to use Kaggle API pythonically.

Assuming you've already exported the username and key as environment variables

```
import os
os.environ['KAGGLE_USERNAME'] = '<kaggle-user-name>'
os.environ['KAGGLE_KEY'] = '<kaggle-key>'
os.environ['KAGGLE_PROXY'] = '<proxy-address>' ## skip this step if you are not working behind a firewall
```

or
you've successfully downloaded `kaggle.json` from the API section in your *Kaggle* Account page and copied this JSON to `~/.kaggle/` i.e. the *Kaggle* configuration directory in your system.

Then, you can use the following code in your *Jupyter* notebook to load this dataset to a *pandas* dataframe:

1. Import libraries

```
import kaggle as kg
import pandas as pd
```

2. Download the dataset locally

```
kg.api.authenticate()
kg.api.dataset_download_files(dataset="START-UMD/gtd", path='gt.zip', unzip=True)
```

3. Read the downloaded dataset

```
df = pd.read_csv('gt.zip/globalterrorismdb_0718dist.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked this way. But I get this warning: /home/nbuser/anaconda3_420/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2728: DtypeWarning: Columns (4,6,31,33,61,62,63,76,79,90,92,94,96,114,115,121) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result).

Comment: Also, could you please explain to me what is this line doing exactly, so I can apply it next time too:
kg.api.dataset_download_files(dataset="START-UMD/gtd", path='gt.zip', unzip=True) ?

Comment: @Yana one your first question read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/27232309/1561981 



On your second question, see https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api/blob/775b1f74c64d139514f8beab2548ce4d62a0cf93/kaggle/api/kaggle_api_extended.py#L1112

Comment: Ankush, Thank you!