# ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I'm having the following error:

> "ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory"

When I try to read a large dataframe (5 gb), but I am selecting only the columns that interest me and setting the necessary parameters, and even so it does not work. I've tried using `chunks` parameter.

```py
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1', usecols = names_columns, low_memory = False, nrows = 10000)
```

The strange thing is that when I put the parameter `"nrows = 1000"` it works.

I've run dataframes with many more rows than that and it worked perfectly, but this one is giving this error.

Someone has any suggestions?

Comment: A Dataframe with 1000 rows, many columns, and large data types can be a larger object than a Dataframe with 10000 rows, a few columns, and small data types. Perhaps you may benefit from specifying `dtype`? (see the `dtype` argument in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html))

Comment: hi and welcome to SO! Consider removing `low_memory=False` to prevent OOM errors.

Answer (score 1):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27232309):

1. There should not be a need to mess with `low_memory`. Remove that parameter option.
2. Specifying dtypes (should always be done)

Consider the example of one file which has a column called `user_id`. It contains 10 million rows where the `user_id` is always numbers. Adding `dtype={'user_id': int}` to the `pd.read_csv()` call will make pandas know when it reads the file, that this is only integers.