# Issue with reading a text file in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to import a txt file which has around 56 columns and has different data types.

Few columns have values with prefix 000, which I cannot see once the data has been imported.

I am also getting the error message "specify `dtype` option on reading or set `low_memory=false"`.

Values in certain columns have changed to `"NaN"` & `"4.40578e+01"`, which is not correct...

I want the data to be imported and displayed correctly.

This is code that I am using

```
from os import os path
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\abc\desktop\file.txt",sep=",")
df.head()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas read\_csv low\_memory and dtype options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251219/pandas-read-csv-low-memory-and-dtype-options)

Comment: Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251219/pandas-read-csv-low-memory-and-dtype-options). Somebody has already answerd your question.