# Will you be notified when you specify wrong dtype for columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, parsing

- I am working with very large dataset that won't fit on my RAM (which
  is 16GB).
- I noticed that the columns `dTypes` are all `float64`, but values in the first 10k rows range from `-1.0` to `+1.0`
- To check the full dataset would take too much time

I want to specify the `dtype` in the `read_csv` for all columns to `float16` to reduce the necessary memory:

```
types = {}

for column in only_first_row_dataframe.columns:
    types[column ] = 'float16'

...

dataframe = pd.read_csv(path, engine="c", dtype = types, lowmemory = False)
```

**After running the above code would I be notified that some values didn't fit into the 16 bit float, and therefor some data were lost?**

---

- I am asking this question because I tested only the first 10k rows if they fit into the range `(-1.0, +1.0)`
- So I want to be sure I won't lose any data.
- When I do run the code I do not have any warnings and the Dataset is loaded into my RAM, but I am not certain if any data were lost.
- According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27232309/11101156) I will be notified if there is a major error in `dtypes`, so for example if column `A` will have `string` value at the end but I specified the `dtype` as `int`. But there is no mention about the problem I am asking here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned you will have an error raised if you have a major `dtypes` error (for example using `int64` when the column is `float64`). However, you won't have an error if for example you use `int8` instead of `int16` and the range of your values does not match the range of `int8` (i.e -128 to 127)

Here is a quick example:

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

s = """col1|col2
150|1.5
10|2.5
3|2.5
4|1.2
8|7.5
"""

pd.read_csv(StringIO(s),sep='|', dtype={"col1": "int8"})
```

And the output is:

```
    col1    col2
0   -106    1.5
1   10  2.5
2   3   2.5
3   4   1.2
4   8   7.5
```

So as you can see, the first value in the column `col1` has been converted from 150 to -106 without any error / warning from pandas.

The same is applied to float types, I just used int for convenience.

**EDIT** I add an example with floats since this is what you were asking:

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

s = """col1|col2
150|32890
10|2.5
3|2.5
4|1.2
8|7.5
"""
```

If you read it without specifying the `dtype`:

```
pd.read_csv(StringIO(s),sep='|'))

   col1     col2
0   150  32890.0
1    10      2.5
2     3      2.5
3     4      1.2
4     8      7.5
```

If you read it with specifying the "wrong" dtype for the columns:

```
pd.read_csv(StringIO(s),sep='|', dtype={"col1": "int8", "col2": "float16"})

   col1          col2
0  -106  32896.000000
1    10      2.500000
2     3      2.500000
3     4      1.200195
4     8      7.500000
```

---

If you have a large CSV file and you want to optimize the dtypes, you can load the CSV file column by column (this should not take too much memory) with no dtype then infer the optimal dtype thanks to the values inside the column and load the full CSV with the optimized dtypes.

Comment: Okay thank you for the info this is what I was looking for!