# having problems merging two csv files

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```py
import pandas as pd
    
csv2 = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
data2 = pd.read_csv('data2.csv')
    
output2 = pd.merge(csv2, data2, on = 'AccountGuid', how='inner')
    
    
print(output2)
```

```
syntax - sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (0,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,16,19,20,21,23,24,25) have mixed types.Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\story.py", line 6, in <module>
    output2 = pd.merge(csv2, data2, on = 'AccountGuid', how='inner')
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 106, in merge
    op = _MergeOperation(
```

Please, any answer on how to fix it will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas read\_csv low\_memory and dtype options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251219/pandas-read-csv-low-memory-and-dtype-options)

Comment: Hi, can you provide an example of the content of `data.csv.`, `data2.csv` and the output expected? Ideally, you should provide a [example] when submitting a question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.