# Dealing with greater than and less than values in numeric data when reading csv in pandas

Tags: pandas

My csv file contains numeric data where some values have greater than or less than symbols e.g. ">244". I want my data type to be a float. When reading the file into pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

I get a warning:

> Columns (2) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.

I have checked this question: [Pandas read_csv: low_memory and dtype options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251219/pandas-read-csv-low-memory-and-dtype-options) and tried specifying the date type of the relevant column with:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',dtype={'column':'float'})
```

However, this gives an error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '>244'

I have also tried

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',dtype={'column':'float'}, error_bad_lines=False)
```

However this does not solve my problem, and I get the same error above.

My problem appears to be that my data has a mixture of string and floats. Can I ignore any rows containing strings in particular columns when reading in the data?

Comment: `>244` is not float, use `df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',dtype={'column':'str'})`

Comment: OK. To clarify, I don't want my datatype to be a string, can I ignore the strings when reading in the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', dtype={'column':'str'})
```

Then:

```
df['column'] = pd.to_numeric(df['column'], errors='coerce')
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround which was read in my data

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

Then remove any values with '<' or '>'

```
df = df.loc[df['column'].str[:1] != '<']
df = df.loc[df['column'].str[:1] != '>']
```

Then convert to numeric with pd.to_numeric

```
df['column'] = pd.to_numeric(df['column'])
```