# low_memory = True in pd.read_csv()

Tags: python, pandas

low_memory = True --> parameter of pd.read_csv() in pandas loads the data in chunks in memory. But in the end we have a entire dataframe in the memory. However when we set low_memory = False, its load the entire dataset into memory which get read into dataframe at a time. Again the whole dataframe is in the memory. So how low_memory = True is saving the memory? What actually this low_memory is doing under the hood. I go through the pandas documentation but not getting anything from there..

Answer (score 1):

`low_memory=True` does not do anything anymore since it has been [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251219/pandas-read-csv-low-memory-and-dtype-options).

**Main idea:** setting `low_memory=True` saves memory during parsing by parsing the dataframe in chunks rather than all at once.

**Details:**

Looking at line 408 of the pandas github repo [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py), we see the following comment.

```
low_memory : bool, default True
    Internally process the file in chunks, resulting in lower memory use
    while parsing, but possibly mixed type inference.  To ensure no mixed
    types either set ``False``, or specify the type with the ``dtype`` parameter.
    Note that the entire file is read into a single :class:`~pandas.DataFrame`
    regardless, use the ``chunksize`` or ``iterator`` parameter to return the data in
    chunks. (Only valid with C parser).
```

Comment: Where it is written that low_memory = True is deprecated?

Comment: If you read clicked into the hyperlink which I mentioned that it is deprecated, you would find another StackOverflow page which has an answer explaining how it is deprecated. Alternatively you can follow [this link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/5888)